# Autocompletion does not work for standard header in neovim

Tags: autocomplete, neovim, clangd

I followed the instructions in [The perfect Neovim setup for C++](https://youtu.be/lsFoZIg-oDs).
But when I try the suggested test for completion (at 6:20) I do not get the wanted autocompletion. I.e. no suggestion for std::

I expected to get autocompletion with several suggestions for std:: and to have #include  added automatically.
I added #include  and std::cout << "message" << std::endl; but got the messages 'iostream' file not found. And Use of undeclared identifier 'std'.

I have experimented with compile_commands.json and with .clangd. Nothing helps. Can anybody direct med to a solution.

The program:

```
#include "iostream"

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
  std::cout << "message" << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

compile_commands.json:

```
[
  {
    "arguments": [
      "/usr/lib64/ccache/bin/g++",
      "-c",
      "-O3",
      "main.cpp"
    ],
    "directory": "/home/hansmicheelsen/udvikling/test",
    "file": "/home/hansmicheelsen/udvikling/test/main.cpp"
  }
]
```

.clangd:

```
CompileFlags: # Tweak the parse settings
  Add: 
    - "-I=/usr/include/c++/12/"
      "-I=/usr/include/c++/12/x86_64-mageia-linux/"
```

My system is Mageia 9.0. And neovim is version NVIM v0.10.0-dev-1009+ga1bec02c1

Comment: Have a look at https://clangd.llvm.org/troubleshooting#cant-find-standard-library-headers-map-stdioh-etc, and `--query-driver` in particular (for more in depth info on it, see https://clangd.llvm.org/guides/system-headers#query-driver). Adding standard library paths manually in `.clangd` should not be necessary.

Comment: Also a note for future reference, `-I=/path` is not a valid option syntax. On the command line, it needs to be either `-I/path` (no separator), or `-I path` (space separator). In `.clangd`, if you go with the second option (space separator), the two tokens would need to go on separate lines (so it's simpler to go with the first option).